# Using String.Join for multiple items in a List

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have an entity like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public string TaskID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of Tasks like:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(new Task() { TaskID = "1", Description = "A", IsComplete = "Yes" });
tasks.Add(new Task() { TaskID = "2", Description = "B", IsComplete = "No" });
```

I am trying to get the following delimited `string` from this collection:

`1#Yes,2#No`

I've managed to get as far as:

```
string delimitedString = String.Join(",", tasks.ToList().Select(l => l.TaskID));
```

...How do I further select and separate additional fields?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this:

```
string delimitedString = 
           string.Join(",", tasks.Select(
                                  l => string.Format("{0}#{1}", l.TaskID, l.IsComplete)));
```

If you're using C#-6:

```
string delimitedString = 
            string.Join(",", tasks.Select(
                                   l => $"{l.TaskID}#{l.IsComplete}"));
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. You left out a closing bracket btw

Answer (score 5):

You could do it the way [Yuval Itzchakov proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32353098/1344058), but I'd rather implement a new method in `Task` that you can call - just to keep it easier to read.

```
public class Task
{
    ...
    public String ToDelimitedString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}#{1}", TaskId, IsComplete);
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var delimString = String.Join(",", tasks.Select(t => t.ToDelimitedString()));
```

This way you have your format in one place and can call it from anywhere without inconsistencies.

By the way: I'd also try to find a different name for the class to avoid any possible confusion with [System.Threading.Tasks.Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is to implement a ToString for the Task, so it displays what you want.

If you can't (it isnt your code), implement a separate function:

```
private string StringifyTask(Task task)
{
    return string.Format("{0}#{1}", task.TaskId, task.IsComplete);
}
```

And then use StringifyTask as the argument of Select. Also - note you don't actually need the ToList before the Linq statement.